# Get elements of vector by non-given indexes in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing

I have the following:

```
a = [1:10 1:10];
idx = [3 5 7];

b = a(idx);
b = [3 5 7];

c = a(~idx); %this syntax is not correct!
c = [1 2 4 6 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
```

is there a straight forward way to get `c` like this? In other words I have an vector and I want to exclude the elements at the given indexes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Explicit way: generate a negated logical index:

   ```
   logical_idx = true(1,numel(a));
   logical_idx(idx) = false;
   c = a(logical_idx);
   ```
2. More compact code using [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) or [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

   ```
   c = a(setdiff(1:numel(a), idx));
   ```

   or

   ```
   c = a(~ismember(1:numel(a), idx));
   ```
3. Directly remove elements indexed by `idx`:

   ```
   c = a;
   c(idx) = [];
   ```

Comment: I've edited the question. In this case solution 2 won't work right?

Comment: Why? I think it does work. It uses indices, not values of `a`

Comment: I haven't tested, and it may depend on vector size. But I'd go for the first

Comment: Well, I've tested, as you said first one is fastest. Second fastest is the last one. The one using `setdiff` is the slowest and the one uses `ismember` is in the third place.